# Blender move item rig?

Tags: animation, game-engine, rigging

I have been trying to rig a weapon, but I don't have much experience. I know how to rig characters though. I don't know about anything, and I am not asking for anyone to actually rig my weapon. I just wanted to know how to do the following rig type: a bone that basically just controls a piece of the object as if you are grabbing it. I just want my magazine come out of the weapon and back in, also, have my entire weapon push back when firing. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make this piece of object separated (in edit mode, to make them still be 1 object), add bone in edit mode either with add armature or shift D and weight paint the armature of the object and if u want to make the object bone parented to main bone, just add parent inside edit mode with keep offset.
i think this should help

Comment: Yeah, now that I realize, I just fell into a major brain-fart. I knew this all along, and it is very simple. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2):

Create the gun and magazine separately, parent the gun to an empty 'gunEmpty' and magazine to another 'magEmpty' then parent (with offset) a third empty 'magslotEmpty' to the gunEmpty but line it up with the slot for the magazine.  Now add a "copy location" constraint to the magEmpty (copying the magslotEmpty), tweak the positions of the geometry relative to the empties, so the magazine and slot lineup nicely. Now the influence slider of the copy location constraint can be used to attach and unattach the magazine. Additionally you could add an empty to a characters hand and give the magazine a copy location constraint to attach to the hand... This also can be done with bones but empties keep it simpler.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't realise it was a game engine issue.  (I have zero game engine experience.)